# "Read more" button references the front page

Tags: views, 8

I manually created a view page with 3 fields: image, title, and body.

The body field has a *Read more* link which, instead of pointing to the specific node listed in the blog, it redirects to the front page.

I didn't track anything that would cause it. Maybe I'm missing something.

> [image: screenshot]

I also tried to use the *[node:nid]* token, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is 2 issues:

1. You're missing a field on your view to reference. In order to reference the Node ID in your view you'll need to add the field *Content: ID* so that it can be referenced in replacement patterns. It will also need to be ***ordered before your body field*** so that its value can referenced. You can use the **Exclude from display option** if you do not want it appearing in your view.
2. The format for token replacement has changed with D8. It's now Twig-like: `{{ field_name }}`. By default the *Content: ID* field should use the field name `nid` so your **More link path** value should be `/node/{{ nid }}`.